# Enlarge element on hover but keep original hover area

Tags: css, hover

I have an image I want to enlarge when I hover over it but I don't want to increase the area that the hover accepts. AKA, when I hover over it. I don't want to make it so you have to move your mouse farther away to leave the element.

I don't have the luxury of modifying the html or using javascript as I'm modifying a page's css.

These are the elements I'm working with.

```
<tbody class="list-item" style="">
    <tr class="list-table-data">
        <td class="data number"/>
        <td class="data image">
            <a class="link sort">
                <!--What I want to enlarge-->
                <img class="hover-info image">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've tried numerous combinations of ::before and selectors to get it to work. Often times the result just leaves a flickering.

Is this possible to do with pure css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible path to pursue is using `position: relative;` and `z-index: -1;` on `.image`, and keeping the `:hover` pseudo-class on `.link`. I've set up a demonstration here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLwPEY

I'm taking some liberties with the styles, but simply for demonstrative purposes.

I'm not sure what you want the result to be (e.g. image stays centered, or exactly how the image size changes), but this may be a start. Note that the effect seems to be glitchy (for me, at least) when mousing out above or below - if you mouse out quickly but then pause on the edge of the image, the hover state seems to persist. Not sure why, and I've tried several different things to troubleshoot it with no success.

Anyway, it might be a place to start.

Comment: That works great but unfortunately the z-index is one of the things I want to increase upon hovering so that's a no go. :\

Comment: That would have been useful information up front. Perhaps you can give us a better idea of what you actually need to have happen.

Either way, you can increase z-index of `.link` and of `.image` on hover if need be. But if you need `.image` to have a z-index higher than that of `.link`, you may be out of luck on this one.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason my thought process was z-index of -1 was special. This works perfectly now! So does setting the z-index to less than the parent always disable hovering?

Comment: Yep. Normally a child is always rendered above its parent, but applying z-index takes that element out of the normal stacking order. So when the child has a lower z-index it is rendered 'below' the parent, and interaction is blocked by the parent - even if the parent element no content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enlarge the image when you hover over the anchor and ensure that the anchor's diameter is staying the same and that it's overflow is visible.

Comment: I tried that with the following CSS yet it had no effect. Am I not setting up the overflow correctly?

.data.image .link.sort {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 70px !important;
}
.data.image .link.sort .image {
  width: 48px;
  height: 68px;
}
.data.image .link.sort:hover .image {
  width: 96px;
  height: 136px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I misread your post and missed the fact that you can only use CSS to accomplish. I adjusted my solution to work within your existing constraint. The technique is similar, the parent `a` uses the `z-index` to be "over" the `img`. I added a border to the `a` so you can see that it remains the same size even with the enlargement of the child `img` when you hover over `a`.

Will this work for you?

```css
a.link > img.hover-info {
  width: 135px;
  height: 155px;
  transition: 500ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -999;
}

a.link {
  display: block;
  width: 135px;
  height: 155px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  z-index: 999;
}

a.link:hover > img.hover-info {
  width: 270px;
  height: 310px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="list-item" style="">
    <tr class="list-table-data">
        <td class="data number"/>
        <td class="data image">
            <a class="link sort">
                <!--What I want to enlarge-->
                <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png" class="hover-info image">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But didn't OP say "I don't have the luxury of modifying the html"?

Comment: This would work but I'm not able to insert any new elements into the html. I've tried combinations of doing this with a ::before on .link.sort and an after on .data.number to no avail. It seems that the + operator does not work with ::before and ::after.

Comment: Sorry @trigger_death, I missed the constraint that you cannot change the HTML. I updated my solution to work within your constraint. Please take another look and see if this will help now.

Comment: Yours and Daniel's answer both ended up being the same and with some explanation about the z-index it works perfectly. Thank you.